# Preferred way to check if query is successful

Tags: mysqli

When checking if a query was successful, what is better?

This

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM `table`"; 
$mysqliResult = $mysqli->query($query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($mysqliResult)) {

}
```

Or this:

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM `table`"; 
$mysqliResult= $mysqli->query($query);

if(get_resource_type($mysqliResult) === 'mysqli result') {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Neither.**

Firs one **is not an option** at all. It'just inapplicable, as empty result is a legitimate result as well - the query was a success anyway.
Besides, in case of an unsuccessful query, this very code will throw an error itself!

The second one could be used for the purpose, but this approach is outdated and extremely inconvenient.

Instead, set mysqli in exception throwing mode, and you will need no code to test for success at all!

Comment: It's no use to test every query for success. Just let it report an error by itself, if happens

Answer (score 0):

First option is better because your are checking only query is success or not but second option we use that when we need to check  values and data type are equal ,**so first is better**

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning